# Why is Django logging not working with Gunicorn?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have a django site with is behind a gunicorn server. 
Here are the logging settings for django -

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s][%(levelname)s] %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': os.environ['DJANGO_LOGLEVEL'],
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/mnt/storage/logs/django.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': os.environ['DJANGO_LOGLEVEL'],
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Here is the command which starts gunicorn server -

```
gunicorn training_service.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 4 --access-logfile /mnt/storage/logs/access.log --log-file /mnt/storage/logs/gunicorn.log --log-level $GUNICORN_LOGLEVEL
```

Now, my understanding is that both the logging frameworks should work completely independent of each other. 
But when I launch the django site by calling `manage.py runserver` logging works are expected from the django settings.

But when I launch the same thing using the gunicorn command both the logging format and the debug logs from django disappear.  I am not sure what is wrong here because `disable_existing_loggers` is also set to false. And I don't know if there is any setting in gunicorn which should effect django's logging functionality.

The only difference is Debug is set to False when I run with gunicorn.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, in my views.py, I have the following line

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("logger_name")
```

I printed logger.__dict__, and it turned out that logger had Disabled=True
So, I changed it to False before doing any info/debug/error etc.

```
logger.disabled = False
```

Then It worked like a charm